# Skype causes blue screen of death

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I don't know why but I have experienced 3 times already that when I launch skype for Windows I get a BSOD. Has somebody experienced this before? What solutions can you suggest?
If you need more details please feel free to comment.
Here's a screenshot from bsod viewer:

[image]

And here's the full report:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27328449/report.html

Comment: `usbvideo.sys` looks like it has to do with a webcam; if you have one, which manufacturer/model is it?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the webcam drivers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the information given, it seems the webcam driver is throwing an unhandled exception when the webcam is accessed.  As drivers run in kernel mode, an unhandled exception thrown by a driver is tantamount to a unhandled kernel exception, crashing the system.  This likely indicates that the driver has malfunctioned trying to access the webcam or has otherwise encountered an unrecoverable problem.

Make sure the webcam driver is installed properly and up to date.  Check if the webcam is operating correctly and correctly connected to the computer.  If this doesn't work, you'll need to uninstall the webcam driver, buy a new webcam, and use the drivers for that webcam.

Comment: I'm using a laptop, and I havent installed a driver for my webcam but it works. I guess I'll just have to lookup some drivers for the webcame then. Thanks!